# unkown data in chat, please explain (rocket.chat only)

Tags: html, web, chat, rocket.chat

Some weird glitch or unknown feature for web and windows/desktop application.

When typing the following:
 Any Message which is then Wrapped in Code, StrikeThrough, Italics and bold as below real-world example/preview which is also marked as a multi-line.

[image: Example Preview of Chat textbox]

when sending/posting it in the chat, it will display as follows. (note: only name and date/time is marked out, due to company specs, hosted locally on internal servers, etc, etc..)

[image: Same as preview as Example above]

Both these images are of the exact same "data"/"text"

please explain what this is for and/or if it is meant to be avalible as a feature, is a bug, or if it is encryption of some sorts, what is this data and how do I undo it??? or disable this if it is a bug..

Thank You, Dean :)

Comment: My _guess_ is that your particular markup (which can be construed as convoluted Markdown) confuses some part of Rocket.chat's message parser. The data looks like a random memoization marker of some sort.

Comment: I hope [this](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/pull/7454) will fix your issue.

Comment: @xerx593 I'll submit a bug report with that link, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fix recommanded by @xerx593

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/pull/7454

I will/have submitted a bug request regarding this.

it seems to be an issue within rocket.chat's markdown parser.